# Edit text created in Grid Layout any Text typed not visible properly

Tags: android, android-edittext

A sample code where i need to have a Edit Text in a Grid Layout Problematically .But when the text are entered ,Only the small bottom portion of text is visible .The text is larger than expected. I need the edit text with text as shown in image which is Edit Text green background with only one line edit text required.Thanks

```
package com.example.myapplicationtesting;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.GroupContainer);
        GridLayout Glyout;// = findViewById(R.id.Glayout_item);
        Glyout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.id_grid) ;

        Glyout.setColumnCount(4);
        Glyout.setRowCount(20);
        int rowIndex = 0 ;



        // Create EditText
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++)
        {
            rowIndex     = i ;
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.height = 50;//ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.width = 250 ;// GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
            param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);

            param.setMargins(0,5,0,0);

            editText.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            editText.setTextSize(10);
            editText.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            editText.setLayoutParams(param);
            if (rowIndex == 1) {
                editText.setId( R.id.task1);
            }
            if (rowIndex == 2) {
               editText.setId(R.id.task2);
            }

            //editText.setHeight(30);
           // editText.setWidth(180);
           // editText.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            Glyout.addView(editText);
            rowIndex++;
        }



   }


}
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, or any new code you'd tried, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you included the image correctly there, but, in the future, please just edit the original. Thanks!

Comment: ok. Accidently posted without images attached. Then did not know where to insert the image in original post.